# Emailing the contents of a Textbox with Outlook

Tags: c#, textbox, email

I have a simple application written that allows users to pick inventory items with checkboxes. When the items are checked a textbox is populated showing the user's input. I would like to have a class that would take the contents of the textbox and copy it to a new outlook email with the TO address pre-populated with myemail@gmail.com. ASP.Net is foreign to me and I am a very new C# coder SO I have no idea how to do this. Any ideas.

I have seen an example online as follows...

```
 System.Web.Mail.MailMessage message=new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
 message.Fields.Add( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate",1 );
 message.Fields.Add( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername","SmtpHostUserName" );
 message.Fields.Add( "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword","SmtpHostPassword" );

 message.From="from e-mail";
 message.To="to e-mail";
 message.Subject="Message Subject";
 message.Body="Message Body";
 System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer="SMTP Server Address";
 System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(message);
```

but I have errors everywhere and think that I'm not implementing this right. Is there a simpler way to do this or just a way I might be able to understand. Thanks to any and all answers. I can only check one but I appreciate them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310263

I am guessing you are not using the Outlook object library. If you want to, then the code is right there.

The only change you will have to make will be

```
  oMsg.Body = TextBox1.text;
```

where TextBox1 has the all the contents that you wanted to send as the message body.

Comment: Error: TextBox1.text doesn't exist. Can I not use inheritance to take care of this? Or should I just change the namespace?

Comment: I thought you said you had a textbox in your form? What is it named?

See, if it is under this.TextBox1.text or Form1.TextBox1.text

Comment: It is named TextBox1 but its on the form and I wanted to practice encapsulation and make the email part its own class. So its looking for the textbox but its on the form1.cs.

Comment: In the declaration of outlook class, make it `public class Outlook : Form1` and you can access the TextBox from form1.cs as Form1.TextBox1.text, provided the textbox has been declared as public, which I think it is by default.

Comment: Form1. I have a submit button that calls a stringbuilder method to populate it so the code is just private void textbox1_Textchanged(...Args e) { }

Comment: Great that worked! One last thing this outlook class has a main method ... isn't that a no no? Should I change that to something? I was under the impression there should only be one main()

Comment: Go to the designer of form1, and right click on the Textbox, and you will see what the modifier is. The textbox1_changed() is just a method that handles changes to textbox1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3806/discussion-between-2boolornot2bool-and-roymustang86)